# Make agenda view only show DONE & CANCEL items

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

How can I filter the agenda view of org-mode for a custom sequence of TODO keywords?

Example: Only show agenda items with one of the TODO-keywords DONE or CANCEL.

Answer (score 1):

Select menu item `Org`>`Agenda Command...` and press <kbd>T</kbd> for "TODO keyword".

Input `TODO|CANCEL` when you are prompted for `Keyword (or KWD1|KWD2|...):`.